# Demonstrating the variation in a trajectory varies when the parameters vary discretely

Tags: differential-equations, function-construction, manipulate

I'm new to Mathmatica, and I'm trying to practice using manipulate.

My Code:

```
Clear["Global *"];
g = 9.8;
Rho = 1.2;
dC = 0.3;
A = (0.037^2)*Pi;
m = .145;
Vo = 90;
Xo = 0;
Vox = Vo*Cos[45 Degree];
Yo = 10;
Voy = Vo*Sin[45 Degree];
tMax = 10;

traj = NDSolve[{-.5*Rho*dC*A*Sqrt[(x'[t]^2) + (y'[t]^2)]*x'[t] == 
    m*x''[t], -m*g - .5*Rho*dC*A*Sqrt[(x'[t]^2) + (y'[t]^2)]*y'[t] == 
    m*y''[t], x[0] == Xo, 
   x'[0] == Vox, y[0] == Yo, y'[0] == Voy}, {x, y}, {t, 0, tMax} ]

ParametricPlot[
Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. traj], {t, 0, tMax}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

I want to make it where Yo and Vo are dependent on age, and manipulate age by hitting buttons(not a slider). Ex: age 10, Yo = 1.5, Vo = 45. This also means making Vox and Voy functions of Vo[age].

so Vo[age], Yo[age], Vox[Vo[age]], Voy[Vo[age]]

Then i want to make Vox and Voy also dependent on theta, and manipulate that with a slider, and also changing NDSolve

so Vox[Vo[age], theta], Voy[Vo[age], theta]

my biggest issue now is defining Vo and Yo, since they are really more like a table of values than a function

age,    Vo,         Yo

- 8,   17.8816,    1.143
- 9,   19.2227,    1.2446
- 10,  20.5638,    1.2954
- 11,  21.4579,    1.3208
- 12,  22.352,     1.4732
- 13,  24.1402,    1.5748
- 14,  26.8224,    1.6002

Comment: Have you checked the docs for manipulate, under examples->scope->controls?  As for the rest, can you show us something you've tried?  At the very least you could tell us what the functional forms for all of the variables in terms of each other should be.

Comment: Also, see the tutorial on [defining functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'm still new to this documentation and didn't know where to look. The setter bar section seem to be what I'm after.

Comment: Everything i've tried so far has broken everything. My Syntax knowledge is pretty weak. Right now my biggest question is How to define the functions Yo and Vo with respect to age, since age is not a range of values, but a table of values

Comment: (When you reply to my comments, be sure to notify me with @jjc385.)  Can you tell us in non-mathematica notation how the variables will depend on one another?  Otherwise we can only guess what you need.  Please add this by editing the question, and feel free to notify me by comment when you've done so.

Comment: @jjc385 ok i think i understand, and made edits in my original post

Comment: I apologize if I was unclear, and thanks for making the edit you did.  Can you also give us all the information we need to calculate `Vo` and `Yo` as a function of age?

Comment: @jjc385 no problem just getting used to all the different terms. just posted the table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First step is to set up `Vo` and `Yo`

```
Clear["Global *"];
Vo[8] = 17.8816;
Yo[8] = 1.143;
Vo[9] = 19.2227;
Yo[9] = 1.2446;
Vo[10] = 20.5638;
Yo[10] = 1.2954;
Vo[11] = 21.4579;
Yo[11] = 1.3208;
Vo[12] = 22.352;
Yo[12] = 1.4732;
Vo[13] = 24.1402;
Yo[13] = 1.5748;
Vo[14] = 26.8224;
Yo[14] = 1.6002;
```

In the `Manipulate` use `Initialization` to set up the variables that do not change.

A `DynamicModule` is inserted inside the `Manipulate` to compute the variables that change (i.e., `Vox`, `Voy` and `traj`).

In the controls `age` has a small range of values (8 to 14) which we force to be buttons by using `ControlType->SetterBar`. If you leave it alone you will get a `PopupMenu` which really is what you want if you allow a larger range for the `age`.

`theta` uses a normal slider bar and it has the `Appearance` set to open so that one sees the value and can quickly edit by typing (this is totally optional).

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[
  {
   Vox = Vo[age]*Cos[theta Degree],
   Voy = Vo[age]*Sin[theta Degree],
   traj
   },

  traj = NDSolve[{
     -.5*Rho*dC*A*Sqrt[(x'[t]^2) + (y'[t]^2)]*x'[t] == m*x''[t],
     -m*g - .5*Rho*dC*A*Sqrt[(x'[t]^2) + (y'[t]^2)]*y'[t] == m*y''[t],
     x[0] == Xo,
     x'[0] == Vox,
     y[0] == Yo[age],
     y'[0] == Voy
     },
    {x, y},
    {t, 0, tMax}
    ];

  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. traj],
   {t, 0, tMax},
   PlotRange -> Automatic, 
   PlotStyle -> Black,
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
  ],

 {{age, 8}, {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, ControlType -> SetterBar},
 {{theta, 45}, 0, 360, Appearance -> "Open"},

 Initialization :>
  {
   g = 9.8,
   Rho = 1.2,
   dC = 0.3,
   A = (0.037^2)*Pi,
   m = .145,
   Xo = 0,
   tMax = 10
   }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, I was able to understand and make some changes to suit my needs. Showed me a lot on what i can do, and how manipulate works. Never occurred to me i can make plot points for Yo and Vo

Answer (score 1):

I was a little slower then Jack LeVigne in producing an answer. This is very similar to his answer, but perhaps enough different to be worth posting.

```
g = 9.8;
Rho = 1.2;
dC = 0.3;
A = (0.037^2)*Pi;
m = .145;
Xo = 0;
tMax = 10;
paramTable =
  {{8, 17.8816, 1.143}, {9, 19.2227, 1.2446}, {10, 20.5638, 1.2954}, 
   {11, 21.4579, 1.3208}, {12, 22.352, 1.4732}, {13, 24.1402, 1.5748}, 
   {14,26.8224, 1.6002}};

{age, vo, yo} = Transpose[paramTable];
Evaluate @ Array[Vo, Length @ age, First @a ge] = vo
Evaluate @ Array[Yo, Length @ age, First @ age] = yo

DynamicModule[{x, y},
  Manipulate[
    {x, y} = 
      NDSolveValue[
       {-.5*Rho*dC*A*Sqrt[(\[FormalX]'[t]^2) + (\[FormalY]'[t]^2)]*\[FormalX]'[t] ==
          m*\[FormalX]''[t], 
        -m*g - .5*Rho*dC*A*Sqrt[(\[FormalX]'[t]^2) + (\[FormalY]'[t]^2)]*\[FormalY]'[t] == 
          m*\[FormalY]''[t], 
        \[FormalX][0] == Xo, \[FormalX]'[0] == Vo[i]*Cos[45 Degree],
        \[FormalY][0] == Yo[i], \[FormalY]'[0] == Vo[i]*Sin[45 Degree]},
       {\[FormalX], \[FormalY]}, {t, 0, tMax}];
    tEnd = FindRoot[y[t], {t, 2.}][[1, 2]];
    ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, tEnd}, AspectRatio -> 1/2],
    {tEnd, None},
    {{i, 8, "age"}, age}]]
```

Trajectory at age = 9

[image: demo9]

Trajectory at age = 13

[image: demo13]